# JWT token validation on each request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I have developed a simple bakend server in node with jwt authentication, but I still have a question: after the user has correctly logged in and saved the token in the client side should the server validate the token at every user request? For example when accessing the `/profile` route (which takes the user to the profile page), or when for example the user creates a question by sending a post request to `/posts/create` route should I use the method `jwt.verify(...)` to check if the token is correct everytime? Is it correct also to send the jwt access token instead of the refresh token or is this a bad practice?

Comment: Your question should focus on a single issue so it can be properly addressed. You do have to validate the token for every call, anybody could craft a request to your API and not go through your login page

Comment: Yes, validate every time! *Is it correct also to send the jwt access token instead of the refresh token or is this a bad practice?* - What do you mean with that?

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for the reply, you are completely right but I didn't want to open too many questions I will make sure to do this in the future!

Comment: @jps thanks for the reply, I am trying to understand if it is ok to save the accessToken int the client side instead of the refreshToken (because lately I have started to see tons of people are now using the refreshToken for authentication means instead of the accessToken).

Comment: @AndreaDattero It's how we expect questions to be asked at Stack Overflow, you should create separate questions so they can have separate specific answers. StackOverflow does want to help you answer your question but we want the answers to be useful to others, not just you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *see tons of people are now using the refreshToken for authentication means instead of the accessToken* - really? Can you link to an example? Ususally refresh tokens are only used to request a new access token if the old one is expired. But maybe I missed somethig, And don't get me wrong, I'm genuinely curious as I never heard about that.

Comment: @jps here is an example: https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/ I have also talked to other people through social media and they are using the refreshToken too

Comment: @AndreaDattero thanks for the link. *You use a refresh token to obtain new access and ID tokens even if the user is no longer signed in to the authorization server. By using refresh tokens, you don't need to re-authenticate your users whenever they launch the app. Instead, if there is any refresh token available, you can use it to get a new access token silently.*  - I didn't read the full article yet, only had a glimpse and looked what the write about refresh tokens. So far nothing surprising. Use the access token to access protected resources and the refresh token to renew the access token.

Comment: from that I don't see how/where the refresh token is used *instead* of the access token. Both tokens have their role/purpose, reflected in their name. And the access token is not used for authentication, but for authorization. You get the access token after you have been authenticated and then get authorized to access a resource.

Comment: @jps I got the whole idea wrong seems, I am sorry ahah, but last question at the moment I am completely ignoring the use of the refreshToken and I am just using the accessToken and in case the token expires I make the user reauthenticate is this still ok?

Comment: @AndreaDattero don't worry, aren't we here to learn?! And yes, you can work without the refresh token and let the user reauthenticate, though with refresh token it's a better user experience.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should validate each request. That is call middleware. In the first step, you check authentication. After that, you can use it for authorization. You can write role, some permission, or other info in JWT.